# Add a new menu selector element into WordPress nav-menus.php

Tags: menus, navigation

How to build a custom menu selection element in the Menu admin (nav-menus.php) section of WordPress similar to how custom Posttypes/Taxonomies are automatically added in when created and then users can select which ones to a new or existing menu created.

My data in a json file, an array, or database dump which includes the menu's: Name, Title, Url, Class, XFN.

Basically have it load up as a Custom Menu section where user can select which menu and then click ADD to MENU.

Grateful for any direction on this.